# How to run an AHK script in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, autohotkey

I want to call multiple AHK scripts in Excel VBA sequentially.

Is there any command or code for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will run an AHK script:

```
shell("C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe ""C:\Path\To\Script\AHK_Script.ahk""")
```

If you need for the VBA to wait until the AHK script finishes, you could try using the following from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952009:

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "C:\folder\runbat.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```